# React button onClick requires two click to work second time

Tags: reactjs

When the img is pressed the side menu opens fine but when i close the side menu and try to open it again by pressing the img it requires two clicks to open. how do i make it so it works with one click even after i open and close the side menu?

```
const Header = () => {
  let [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <header className='homepage-header'>
        <img src={menusvg} alt='' onClick={() => setIsOpen((isOpen) => !isOpen)} />
        {
            isOpen ? <SideMenu /> : null
        }
        <h1>Main Header</h1>
    </header>
  )
}
```

note: i have another button inside the SideMenu componenet that closes the menu.

SideMenu:

```
function SideMenu() {
  let [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);
  return (
    <>
        {
            isOpen ? <div className='side-menu'>
                <p>side menue</p>
                <i class="fas fa-times" onClick={() => setIsOpen((isOpen) => !isOpen)}></i>
            </div>
                : null
        }
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a callback in your `setIsOpenCall()`? WHy not call `setIsOpen(!isOpen)`?

Comment: hey. tried setIsOpen(!isOpen)  still same issue

Comment: I tried your code everything working fine, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-j4rxot?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I copied your code exactly, and only removed the classname, and substituted `SideMenu` with a `h2` tag, and it worked exactly as expected.

Comment: it works fine as a toggle but i have another button inside the <sideMenu> that closes the menu. so when i close it with that button and try to open it agian it requires two clicks

Comment: It sounds like something in `SideMenu` is circumventing your show/hide logic in state. There's pretty much no way the `SideMenu` button could be doing it correctly since you aren't passing any props to it that could call the state updater.. Please show us how that component is closing the menu.

Comment: how are you closing from within <sideMenu/>, you might need to pass some props to set this property isOpen false

Comment: You're not handling the states correctly, I suggest you read [this chapter](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) from react documentation.

Comment: @BrianThompson i added the side menu code

Comment: Yes, so I think its fairly clear that if you have two completely independent states that both are responsible for managing whether or not the sidebar is open, they will get out of sync... You close the `SideMenu` state, but how can the `Header` state know that it should also be closed?? Read the documentation on lifting state up linked in the comments above on the correct strategy for updating the parent's state from a child component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using two different states, pass `isOpen` and `setIsOpen` as props to `SideMenu`

Try this code

```
function SideMenu({ isOpen, setIsOpen }) {
  return (
    <>
      {isOpen ? (
        <div className="side-menu">
          <p>side menue</p>
          <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(isOpen => !isOpen)}>Close</button>
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
}
```

--

```
export default function App() {
  let [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);
  return (
      <header className="homepage-header">
        <img
          src={'https://picsum.photos/200'}
          alt=""
          onClick={() => setIsOpen(isOpen => !isOpen)}
        />
        {isOpen ? <SideMenu isOpen={isOpen} setIsOpen={setIsOpen} /> : null}
        <h1>Main Header</h1>
      </header>
  );
}
```

Sample Code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-j4rxot?file=src%2FApp.js

Answer (score 0):

The logic you have used to make isOpen true and false is bit wierd,(at least for me), although feels correct.

A simple way would be,

```
const Header = () => {
  let [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <header className='homepage-header'>
        <img src={menusvg} alt='' onClick={() => isOpen ? setIsOpen(false) : setIsOpen(true)} />
        {
            isOpen ? <SideMenu /> : null
        }
        <h1>Main Header</h1>
    </header>
  )
}

Hope it works!
```

Comment: This is way more verbose than what the OP already has and does the same thing. Most importantly, it doesn't attempt to answer the actual question regarding the required double click.

Comment: i tired this. same issue